# How to add new Wordpress page template without switching themes?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Whenever  I add a new page template to my theme, the only way I know how to get it to show up in the list is to switch to a different theme and then switch back. I am wondering if there is a way to reset the theme page options without doing this hack?

Comment: Do you have any cache plug-ins enabled? WP could be clearing the cache after you change themes.

Comment: I usually just refresh the page and the template appears on the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually find that switching to a different page or post reveals any new templates.

Make sure your templates are in your theme directory.

Comment: The templates are in the theme folder. Even when creating a new page, the dropdown for templates doesn't include new files until I switch to and from another theme to reset the list.

Comment: Are you using something like this as the very first line in your .php template page: `<?php /* Template Name: Sitemap */ ?>`

Comment: This needs to be on a line of it's own. I write my template pages with Espresso and upload them directly from there. As soon as I refresh the current page or switch pages/posts the new theme templates show up - even if it is the first new template and the drop-menu (in edit mode) was not visible before. I don't know what else to suggest, unless perhaps there is some function controlling your admin pages that might be worth looking for.